# Advantages/disadvantages of a cylindrical microwave oven cavity in comparison to a rectangular cavity

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, microwaves

*Why are rectangular cavities preferred for standard microwave ovens with a frequency of 2.45 Ghz? What is the reason that you can hardly find a circular cavity? What are the disadvantages of cylindrical cavities? Are there any advantages?*

My assumption is that the radius of a cylindrical cavity would be bigger than the largest side of a rectangular cavity so that the dominant mode can propagate. Maybe the mode propagation in cylindrical ovens is not that good to get a more uniform field distribution and therefore even heating. Are there also reasons of manufacturing?
Any **reference to a paper or book** is very **appreciated**.

==================================================================

Update:

yesterday i found some advantages/disadvantages in literature of circular **waveguides**, but i dont know if i can translate these into cavity resonators:

**advantages:**

1. TE01 mode in circular waveguide has the lowest attenuation per unit length of waveguide hence suitable for distance waveguide transmission.
   --> *since microwave ovens dont want to transfer anything over long distance i think this is negligible*
2. in circular waveguide, TM01 and TE01 modes are rotationally symmetrical and hence rotation of polarization could be overcome. 
   --> *why is this an advantage?*
3. the circular waveguides are easier to manufacture and join than rectangular waveguides.

**disadvantages:**

1. propagation in rectangular waveguide is easier compared to circular waveguide.
2. circular waveguide occupies more space compared to rectangular waveguide system.
3. due to infinite number of modes existing in a circular waveguide, it becomes very difficult to separate these modes.
4. angle of polarization of wave changes because of discontinuities and even small irregularities, as a result of which coupling energy out of waveguide at receiving end becomes difficult. --> *is this what you mean **@CuriousOne**? but why is this a bad thing?*
5. Fabrication of certain type components is more difficult for circular waveguide

Maybe someone with a better understanding of microwaves can briefly explain what (dis-) advantages would be relevant for microwave oven cavities.

Comment: Good question. I would think that it has to do with the ability of a rectangular waveguide to keep the polarization of the wave well defined even when it is bent.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a rectangular microwave oven has the same simple advantage as rectangular furniture: rooms are usually rectangular, and any other shape of furniture would use the space less efficiently.

Comment: ...and you can't conveniently put a flat dish in a cylindrical cavity without wasting space

Answer (score 0):

I am currenly trying to build a cylindrical MW oven here's what I foud out: you dont want TM01 and TE01 modes , that's for a waveguide. For an oven, for the sake of heat distribution you want as many nodes as the cavity can fit (=length/half wavelength)

-pros : can withstand vacuum

-cons:

*[calculating the dimentions is hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_cavity#Cylindrical_cavity). The Bessel derivative calculators are hard to find and inconvenient

*it requires a stand